# How to get a short array from ByteBuf efficiently?

Tags: netty

When using `java.nio.ByteBuffer`，my code is like this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ...
ShortBuffer shortBuffer = buffer.asShortBuffer();
short[] shortArray = new short[shortBuffer .remaining()];
shortBuffer.get(shortArray);
```

Now using netty 4,how can I get the short array from `ByteBuf`efficiently?
Or I just use `ByteBuf.nioBuffer()` to get a `ByteBuffer` first?

And,how to put a short array to `ByteBuf` efficiently?Could I write code like this:

```
Unpooled.buffer(...).nioBuffer().asShortBuffer().put(shortArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netty doesn't have a good mechanism to extract a `Short[]` from a `ByteBuf`. You can use a compound solution that detects the backend type and uses different ways to address this backend, falling back over to simple copying of the underlying array.

The `NioBuffer` case is simple, it has a simple `get()` operation for reading the resulting short array.

The direct and array based cases are harder, these cases require us to call `readShort()` in a loop until we filled the resulting array.

The resulting code would look like:

```java
ByteBuf buf = ...;
short[] result;
if(buf.readableBytes() % 2 != 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
result = new short[buf.readableBytes() / 2];
if (buf.nioBufferCount() > 0 ){
    buf.nioBuffer().asShortBuffer().get(result);
} else {
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = buf.readShort();
    }
}
```